# как выполнить скрипт селениумом с закрытым браузером без окон

Tags: python, selenium

выполняю такой код но все равно вылезают окна браузера.Опции есть.

```
from selenium import webdriver
DRIVER = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER)
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
# Настройка опций Chrome
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--headless")  # запуск Chrome в безголовом режиме
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот префикс всегда есть.Так в безоконном режиме даже его не отдает у некоторых ссылок

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно используете опции. Вот так правильно:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
# Настройка опций Chrome
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--headless")  # запуск Chrome в безголовом режиме

DRIVER = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER, options=options)
```

Comment: большое спасибо